# client authentification to gae server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, client-server, oauth-2.0

I need some general design advices from you. I plan to implement a client to client communication, using a gae server as message router. There are several clients associated to specific users. I planned to use google accaunts for user identification.

But I am not sure how to secure the users data, so that their data is only accessible by them selves. Am I right to use OAuth to protect the communication?

Can anyone direct me into how to use that? I found the [google-oauth-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/), but didn't found any easy to understand tutorial on how to implement a secure communication between a client and gae server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excessive googling brought me to that blog post:
http://fabiouechi.blogspot.de/2011/11/using-google-oauth-java-client-to.html

together with the there in linked blog post:
http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/

I was able to get my example working!